# Center align behavior in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have an image with same width and height which is 60% of the device's width. I want the vertical center of the image to be 45% of the device's height. My code is below:
[image]

I have set constraintTop and constraintBottom to the guideline, but it just like the constraintBottom does not work. The image is just at the bottom of the guideline. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

I have tried to replace 'android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout' to 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'，the result is still not expected:
[image]

I fill the image with blue color to illustrate the problem and the result on my cellphone:
[image]

Comment: This should work . Also i have checked it its working for me . Could it be because of version cause i see you are still using support not `androidX`.  Is also not working as expected when you run it on device ?

Comment: @ADM I have tried 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3', the result is still same. It's also same on my redmi.

Comment: This is quite strange . Now that you posted the actual device screenshot possibility of build issue is gone . can you check it in some other device may be on an Emulator .

Comment: @ADM I download the newest sdk(android 11) and create a virtual device by android studio. The result: https://i.imgur.com/fnyVdfO.png

Comment: I see it's the same . I will look into it . Its better not be some silly mistake we are making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs in version 1.1.3 of *ConstraintLayout* and is, somehow, related to the dimensions of `0dp` and the setting of `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`. This does not occur in version 2.0.4, so upgrade to that release if you can.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have tried update ConstraintLayout to 2.0.4 and it works well.